# Error with second log-in to EasyPHP mySQL local server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, easyphp

I've set up a mySQL local server using EasyPHP and created a user. In the first time, I had no problem logging in using PHP (mysqli). However, after I've shut down the server, and then reopened it, I couldn't log in, and the following error message appeared:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1524): Plugin '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' is not loaded in C:\... on line 26
```

(the actual error showed the exact page location, but I replaced it with "..." here)

The first time it happened, I created another user and it worked... Until I restarted the server again, and couldn't login (got the same error message) :.

I'm using EasyPHP DEVSERVER 16.1.1, MySQL 5.7.11 and PhpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?